# Showing error in syntax on Azure synapse SQL script

Tags: sql, azure-synapse

My code is

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON 
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON 
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[RLS_LOGS] 
WITH (
    DISTRIBUTION = ROUND_ROBIN,
    CLUSTERED COLUMNSTORE INDEX
     )
    AS
    (
    [USER_IDENTITY] [nvarchar](4000) NOT NULL,
    [DESCRIPTION] [nvarchar](4000) NOT NULL,
    [CREATED_ON] [datetime2](7) NOT NULL DEFAULT (GETDATE())
    )
```

Showing the error while running SQL script on azure synapse (Dedicated server pool)

Comment: Dedicated server pool

Comment: Where did you get that Syntax from? Doesn't look like the examples here? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-table-azure-sql-data-warehouse?view=azure-sqldw-latest#ColumnCollation

Comment: Due to GETDATE() its showing error while creating table

Comment: Please update your question with the full error message

Answer (score 1):

You have some of the clauses a bit out of order. This should work:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[RLS_LOGS] 
    (
    [USER_IDENTITY] [nvarchar](4000) NOT NULL,
    [DESCRIPTION] [nvarchar](4000) NOT NULL,
    [CREATED_ON] [datetime2](7) NOT NULL
    )
WITH (
    DISTRIBUTION = ROUND_ROBIN,
    CLUSTERED COLUMNSTORE INDEX
     )
```

I had to remove the getdate() default because as documented [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/specify-default-values-for-columns?view=sql-server-ver15#Restrictions):

> In Azure Synapse Analytics, only constants can be used for a default
> constraint. An expression cannot be used with a default constraint.

You will just have to ensure each INSERT statement inserts getdate() to that column.